# How we click same class name ON button for different field name in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

How we click same class name for ON / OFF button for different field name in selenium webdriver

(eg)
1) Email Notification - one element 
2) System fees - second element
3) Birthdate - third element

these are have same class name - "toggle-group".How we click these three button.

How we write click button action for this 
Not like checkbox option

Comment: You can use "xpath" if you have same class name for all tags/elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the elements by their text

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("first")).click();
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("first")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this very [helpful article](https://loadfocus.com/blog/2013/09/05/how-to-locate-web-elements-with-selenium-webdriver/%20%22helpful%20article), you can use many methods:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("element id"))

driver.findElement(By.className("element class"))

driver.findElement(By.name("element name"))

driver.findElement(By.tagName("element html tag name"))

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css selector"))

driver.findElement(By.link("link text"))

driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath expression"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class check {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       List<WebElement> we = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
       we = driver.findElements(By.name("chk"));
           we.get(0).click(); // clicks on "first"
           we.get(1).click(); // clicks on "second"
           we.get(2).click(); // clicks on "third"

     }
}


/* another option */


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class check {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       List<WebElement> we = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
       we = driver.findElements(By.name("chk"));

       for(WebElement check: we)
       {
           check.click(); // click all the 3 elements and comes out of loop

       }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps..